# iptables with cups - hp printer not visible

Tags: iptables, cups

I have a linux system on which I need to configure the firewall.
Unfortunately scanning the network for printers doesn't work after I set the firewall (without the firewall the the printer is seen).

Printer used - lpinfo -l -v

```
Device: uri = socket://xx.xx.xx.xx:9100
class = network
info = Deskjet 3520 e-All-in-One Printer series
make-and-model = HP Deskjet 3520 series
device-id = MFG:HP;MDL:Deskjet 3520 series;
location =
```

below you can see the rules I am using which were built based on the information I've found at https://www.cups.org/doc/firewalls.html :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 161 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 515 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 9100 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


iptables -nvL

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 8 packets, 788 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:631 state NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:631 state NEW
   23  4228 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5353 state NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   22  3619 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:137
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:138
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:445
```

Do you know what am I missing ?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try actually printing something? From the iptables the only packets dropped were on INPUT, which maybe has something to do with the nmap/nstat report.

Comment: Without the iptables the printing works. My goal is to make it visible in the lpinfo -l -v output. Currently if the iptables rules are used, the printer is not seen by lpinfo.

Comment: Let's see if we can work through this, I would start by confirming the assumption that the issue is with INPUT, with the iptables on lets temporarily change the policy to accept instead of drop with `iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT` . Does the IPinfo work now? If so, great we know where the problem is. Next step would be to enable logging to see the information about why its being dropped `iptables -N LOGGING` `iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING` `iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped: " --log-level 4` `iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP` test and check in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 1):

Using the iptables logging (as suggested by @notsoslimshady) I was able to see what I was previously missing.
The printer is now found as a network printer.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
**iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 161 -j ACCEPT** <-- Missing rule
```

Comment: Yes, the identification of network printers often uses SNMP, which usually uses only UDP in firmware-embedded implementations. More advanced SNMP implementations like `net-snmp` might also have the option of using TCP, but UDP is still the standard default for SNMP.